# Appending to create a list instead of creating a list inside a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, find, append

Currently my code looks as following:

```
data = ""

pattern1 = re.compile('')
pattern2 = re.compile('')
pattern3 = re.compile('')

items = re.findall(pattern1, data 
mainlist = []
for item in items:
    forename = re.findall(pattern2, item)
    surname = re.findall(pattern3, item)
    mainlist.append(surname)
```

The only problem with this layout is that I am getting lists like:

```
[['Smith', 'Patricks', 'Clark'], ['Austin', 'Hamilton', 'Day', 'Sidders'], ['Bennet']]
```

I'm wanting my lists to come out as follows:

```
['Smith', 'Patricks', 'Clark', 'Austin', 'Hamilton', 'Day', 'Sidders', 'Bennet']
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
- Hy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extend`:

```
for item in items:
    forename = re.findall(pattern2, item)
    surname = re.findall(pattern3, item)
    mainlist.extend(surname)
```

`myList.extend(L)` adds the individual elements of `L` onto `myList`. It's similar to:

```
for element in L:
    myList.append(element)
```